# Issue with a Python script. Could you help me to correct this files?

Tags: python, python-2.7, syntax-error

I'm working with some Python files, and there's some errors that I can't resolve. The script isn't mine but the author won't answer me, and I really need this script to works.

Here there is the package: https://github.com/compbio-UofT/FSDA
It works with python2.7.

My error is:

```
1) vcfParser.py", line 30
    print info[0]+"\t"+info[1]+"\t"+str(cA)+"\t"+str(cB)+"\t"+info[3]+"\t"+info[4]#+"\t"+dbsnpinfo[2]
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

2) rm: impossible to remove '/tmp//__tmp_reads_BAMFILE': File or directory don't exist
3) cat: '/tmp//__frags_*_7028': File or directory don't exsit
4) rm: impossible to remove '/tmp//__frags_*_7028': File or directory don't exsit
```

Comment: Which version of python are you running this with?   (`python -V`)

Answer (score 0):

it seems you are trying to run this scripts with python3 to me... Because print function changed in version 3 and now it needs parentheses to run and this code gives the error in this line.

Comment: with this script i use './file.sh' But if I try to use python2.7 or python3.6 I have errors. I have both versions of python. I tryed to modify the script and I inseted the parentheses near with the print function, but I have other error, always in print function.

Comment: UPDATE: i tryed again to modify the file, but I still have this error: rm: impossibile rimuovere '/tmp//__tmp_reads_001_sample01_8211': File o directory non esistente
rm: impossibile rimuovere '/tmp//__tmp_reads_001_sample02_8211': File o directory non esistente
cat: '/tmp//__frags_*_8211': File o directory non esistente
rm: impossibile rimuovere '/tmp//__frags_*_8211': File o directory non esistente

Any idea?